# Extreme points of $f(x)$, using the information below.

Tags: calculus, limits, functions, derivatives, polynomials

The information I know is that $\displaystyle f\left(\frac{3x-5}{6}\right)=\sqrt[6]{x^{13-3x}}-\frac{3x+5}{6}$, but I want to find out how to express the $f(x)$ and calculate its extreme points. Can you help me?

Comment: Yes, have you tried something?

Comment: I know how to calculate the extreme points, but I don't know how to adjust to see how much f(x) is from what I already have but I already realized that there will be some substitution that I don't know what it is.

Comment: Actually, lets precise that the substituion that wrote Grabielek works because it is bijective

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the substitution $y := \frac{3x -5}{6}$ to get $x = \frac{5 + 6y}{3}$.

Now you can substitute in your formula and you get $f(y) = \left(\frac{5 + 6y}{3}\right)^\frac{13 - 5 - 6y}{6} - \frac{5 + 6y + 5}{6}  = \dots$